# Address Sanitization

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, address-sanitizer

Does the Address Sanitizer reports the memory leak only when the program/process stops? While process is running the ASAN log is not generated where as when I stop the process the logs are generated. Is it the correct step to collect ASAN log?

Comment: That depends. Address Sanitizer can detect some errors as they happen (e.g. writing out of bounds, such as past the end of an array, or releasing something twice that can only be released once). Memory leaks are not necessarily like that, since there are many ways in which memory may be leaked (e.g. code that allocates memory may be quite removed in time from code that eventually loses track or forgets to release it) - so some leaks cannot be detected until final cleanup (associated with program termination) is underway.  A sanitizer cannot necessarily  detect all resource leaks either.

Comment: A memory leak is an instance of allocating memory without deallocating it before the program stops. From this perspective, there are no memory leaks until the program stops, so of course they cannot be reported before they exist. *(Some might prefer to define that a leak occurs when there is no longer a pointer to the memory, but that ignores clever ways of recovering a pointer -- for example, perhaps it was reinterpreted as a sufficiently large integer type.)* How would you like to define a memory leak so that one could possibly exist before Address Sanitizer reports it?

Comment: Thanks @Peter and JaMiT for your comments. What I am understanding from this is, If there is one pointer pointing to some memory block and the block of memory is not freed before exiting the process then ASAN will not detect the leak at runtime but when program stops that time it can detect that leak and report?

Comment: @VishwajeetTripute that's correct. You can also detect leaks manually before program exits by explicitly calling `__lsan_do_leak_check`.